# rosws update turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, rosws, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to do the command "rosws update turtlebot", in tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays, I receive this message:

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/vcstools/common.py", line 141, in run_shell_command
>stdout = "\n".join(stdout_buf)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

Exception caught during install: Error processing 'turtlebot' : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

Someone could help me?

ERROR: Error processing 'turtlebot' : 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41767/rosws-update-turtlebot/) by [leo_eng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3047/leo_eng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a bug, apparently, I registered it here:
https://kforge.ros.org/vcstools/trac/ticket/64

I will investigate.

In your case,

```
rosws update turtlebot
```

is just a shortcut for:

```
 hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot
```

so you can do that and then continue the installation

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1